# typdef with template/macro syntax in c++

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

I'm using the eigen library, I simply try to print the eigenvalues in file after solution. Although the result is fairly simple, nothing but a set of floating numbers stored in vector due to the complex nature of returned class type I can not convert them into convertible code or I don't know whether there exist any intrinsic function at all.

```
typedef CwiseBinaryOp<internal::scalar_quotient_op<ComplexScalar,Scalar>,
ComplexVectorType,VectorType> EigenvalueType;
```

The following code is printing on the console screen

```
cout << "The (complex) numerators of the generalzied eigenvalues are: " << ges.alphas().transpose() << endl;
cout << "The (real) denominatore of the generalzied eigenvalues are: " << ges.betas().transpose() << endl;
cout << "The (complex) generalized eigenvalues are (alphas./beta): " << ges.eigenvalues().transpose() << endl;
```

If try to use the below code to write eigenvalues to a file then `error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'Eigen::GeneralizedEigenSolver<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1> >::EigenvalueType {aka class Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_quotient_op<std::complex<float>, float>, Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<float>, -1, 1>, Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, 1> >}' through '...'|` error arises

```
file_in = fopen("result.txt","w");
if (file_in!=NULL )
{
    fprintf(file_in,"aasd");
    fprintf(file_in,"Eigen values are : %f",ges.eigenvalues());
}
fclose(file_in);
```

If I look at the eigenvalues type definition it is EigenvalueType : `typedef CwiseBinaryOp<internal::scalar_quotient_op<ComplexScalar,Scalar>,ComplexVectorType,VectorType> EigenvalueType;` which hints nothing to me.

How am I supposed to convert that class type into floating value

Comment: The [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1GeneralizedEigenSolver.html#acffd08bee548eaa5c10414343a93529f) says "Precondition:
Either the constructor GeneralizedEigenSolver(const MatrixType&,const MatrixType&,bool) or the member function compute(const MatrixType&,const MatrixType&,bool) has been called before." Maybe you forgot to do that?

Comment: Why don't you just use an `fstream`, since you already know writing to a stream (`cout`) works?

Comment: @nwp nope, there is not any problem with the problem solution it solves and retrieves the correct values and properly prints them on console screen, I alread declared `GeneralizedEigenSolver ges` and called it before attempting to printout the values `ges.Solve(A,B);`. Discrepancy is when I try to attempt to write them to a file there is syntax problem with that line `fprintf(file_in,"Eigen values are:%f",ges.eigenvalues());` that I can't figured out.

Comment: @AlanStokes, if it's a proof that `cout` works and so that fstream can be used then it's good entrypoint, using fopen is completely my own matter of taste for IO handling, I'll give it a try. But in any case that declaration `typedef CwiseBinaryOp<internal::scalar_quotient_op<ComplexScalar,Scalar>,
ComplexVectorType,VectorType> EigenvalueType;` is not clear to my perception, I googled for typdef template but there is not much definitive help there.

Comment: You're not normally expected to look into how that sort of type is defined (it's considered an implementation detail) - instead the documentation should specify what you can do with it. Writing to a steam is clearly supported; conversion to a simple float or double may be (or you may be able to iterate over the values if that makes sense).

Comment: @AlanStokes Yes normally not necessary to peek into definitons but I was hoping to find any clue if there was any method which allows me directly to manipulate the stored values so I can perform abs, greater or smaller validation check. Fstream works, prints the values with parantehesis around them is it normal to have parenthesis or is it generally intrinsic feature?

Comment: @Sonya That means Eigen has overloaded the `>>` operator for that type to do that. You might have more luck if you assigned the result to a vector type and then worked with that. (What you have is an expression type - which is the not-yet-evaluated result.)

Comment: You can try to cast ges.eigenvalues() to float. If that does not work you can do something like `stringstream ss; ss << ges.eigenvalues(); fprintf(f, "%s", ss.str().c_str());` to take advantage of Eigen's own function for printing. It is not very efficient but should definitely work.